# Как присвоить переменной со второго по пятый символ заданной строки?

Tags: python

Присвойте переменной `x` значение строки из символов со второй по пятый из строки `txt`.
Нужно присвоить переменной `x` символы со второго по пятый из строки `txt`.

```py
txt = "Hello world"
x = #???
```

Нужно подставить что-то, чтобы программа работала.

Comment: в восьмом классе вроде уже умеют читать. Бери учебник и читай.

Comment: К учебным заданиям принято прикладывать попытки решения. Ждём ваши старания!

Comment: К сожалению ни учебников, ни тетрадей нам не дано. Только интернет, который не помог мне в решении этого задания

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала поговорим об индексах. Индекс - номер определённого элемента в какой-либо последовательности. Строка - тоже последовательность, значит у каждой буквы в ней есть свой номер - индекс. Понятное дело, отсчёт начинается с 0.

```py
s = "Аянами Рей!"
print(s[0])
# Вывод: А
print(s[1])
# Вывод: я
```

Помимо того, что вы можете хотеть выбрать какой-то элемент последовательности, вы также можете хотеть выбрать сразу несколько элементов.
В данном случае вам помогут срезы.

Срезы - это инструмент, с помощью которого вы можете обрезать какую-либо последовательность, оставляя лишь некоторые её элементы.
Синтаксис: [первый_индекс:последний_индекс:шаг]
Например, вы можете срезать первые два символа.

```py
s = "Аянами Рей!"
print(s[2:])
# Вывод: нами Рей!
# в данном случае 'н' имеет индекс 2, поэтому с него начинается строка
```

Или оставить только их.

```py
s = "Аянами Рей!"
print(s[:2])
# Вывод: Ая
# т.е. убираются все буквы со второй до самого конца
```

Или срезать последние два.

```py
s = "Аянами Рей!"
print(s[:-2])
# Вывод: Аянами Ре
# т.е. остаются все буквы, кроме последних двух
```

А можно обрезать сразу со второго по пятый, то что вам и нужно.

```py
s = "Аянами Рей!"
x = s[2:5]
print(x)
# Вывод: нам
# т.е. 2, 3 и 4 символ по счёту
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть [тут](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html) или по запросу в гугл "срезы python"

Comment: СПАСИБО! Я как раз и не знала, как к переменной, 2 значения подставить!

Comment: Если я вам помог, нажмите галочку слева, чтобы выделить правильный ответ